# dos consultas en una sola que no estan unidas entre si

Tags: php, sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla

```
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_empresa` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`ncuenta` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
`dcuenta` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
`fecha` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`fecha_credito` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`fecha_dig` DATE NOT NULL,
`factura` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
`cliente` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
`cedula` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
`detalle` TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
`debe` DOUBLE(20,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`haber` DOUBLE(20,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`saldo` DOUBLE(20,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`asiento` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
`tcc` DOUBLE(20,2) NOT NULL,
`tcv` DOUBLE(20,2) NOT NULL,
`fiscal` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
`exento` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`impuesto` DOUBLE(4,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`cod_subempresa` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`cod_subsub` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

y quiero unir esta consulta

```
SELECT 
 ncuenta,dcuenta,saldo,fiscal
FROM cap_tmp_CUBER WHERE fiscal<='2017-2018' GROUP BY ncuenta
```

y tengo una segunda consulta

```
SELECT 
ncuenta,dcuenta,saldo,fiscal
FROM cap_tmp_CUBER WHERE fiscal<='2018-2019' GROUP BY ncuenta
```

lo que quiero es hacer una consulta sin que interfieran una con otra y que queden una a la par de la otra. Ya probe con inner join pero me da datos de la segunda consulta en la primera y eso es lo que no quiero

Comment: unir una abajo de la otra digamos? como usando UNION?

Comment: Si quieres unir los resultados, la trivial es poner en el WHERE las dos condiciones sobre fiscal: `WHERE (f<=2018 OR f<=2019)`. Usar UNION ALL funcionaría porque tienes los mismos campos pero sería más lento. PD. Me da curiosidad que uses `<=` con un campo VARCHAR

Comment: Porque, a la larga, lo que es menor al período 2018-2019 DEIFNITIVAMENTE es menor o igual al período 2017-2018. Si corres la segunda, no te incluye los resultados de la primera consulta???

Comment: Alfabravo lo pongo de esa manera porque necesito que sean igual o antes del año lo hago en campo varchar porque son periodos fiscales no años

Comment: Y queres que queden a la par de que forma? o sea, que registro de la primera va a quedar a la par de que registro de la segunda? y porque? esto parece ser un problema que tiene que resolver tu vista, no tu base de datos

Comment: vamos a ver si me explico mejor. <br> <consulta1><consulta2>. esto es mas que todo para hacer comparaciones de datos que se compare el año 1 con el año2 de los mismos datos

Answer (score 1):

Deberías utilizar un operador **OR** para que traiga los datos de una consulta u otra y de esta manera tener los datos de ambas.

```
SELECT 
 ncuenta,dcuenta,saldo,fiscal
FROM cap_tmp_CUBER 
WHERE fiscal<='2017-2018' 
OR fiscal<='2018-2019'
GROUP BY ncuenta
```

Sino con **UNION**, que es utilizado para combinar los resultados de dos o más select.

```
SELECT 
 ncuenta,dcuenta,saldo,fiscal
FROM cap_tmp_CUBER 
WHERE fiscal<='2017-2018' 
GROUP BY ncuenta

UNION

SELECT 
ncuenta,dcuenta,saldo,fiscal
FROM cap_tmp_CUBER 
WHERE fiscal<='2018-2019' 
GROUP BY ncuenta
```

Saludos.

Comment: si la accion me la hace eso lo tengo claro sin embargo quiero que queden una a la par de la otra, es decir la consulta uno quede a la izquierda y la consulta dos a la derecha, el union logico si funciona pero no me da los resultados que necesito

Comment: Podrias intentar ejecutar la consulta mediante un select dentro de otro select. SELECT 
 ncuenta,dcuenta,saldo,fiscal,(SELECT 
ncuenta,dcuenta,saldo,fiscal
FROM cap_tmp_CUBER WHERE fiscal<='2018-2019' GROUP BY ncuenta)
FROM cap_tmp_CUBER WHERE fiscal<='2017-2018' GROUP BY ncuenta